# Views Content: Title as an autocomplete exposed filter?

Tags: 7, views, ajax

I would like to provide an **autocomplete widget** for the `Content: Title` in a view (created by Views), in which this field is an exposed filter. By default, it's a **simple textfield**.

What's the best solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Views autocomplete filter](http://drupal.org/project/views_autocomplete_filters)

It will work for node titles and other exposed text fields

Comment: +1, thank you, I've already found this one and [Finder](http://drupal.org/project/finder) module too, what do you think, which is better to use for this task?

Comment: Haven't tried out both modules, however finder looks like an advanced one i.e providing much more features.

Comment: Wow, I just tried Views Autocomplete Filters, and to me, for a really simple autocomplete feature on this field, it's perfect. But the result of the dropdown list can also be output as a link (can be clicked), and the selected value can be put into the field as an HTML `<a>` tag too, if it's needed. Thank you very much, your answer was the first, and it's accepted. :)

Comment: does not work for d6 views 3

Answer (score 3):

I have used the [Finder](https://drupal.org/project/finder) module, but it's too difficult to configure and use. It provides AJAX functionality to return results as a select option while typing. The Finder module is more of a field with auto-complete results.

I would suggest you use the [Views Autocomplete Filters](https://drupal.org/project/views_autocomplete_filters) module which looks more applicable to your problem.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, Anil Sagar! I would rather accept both of your answers, but Mathankumar was the first one, so the fair choice is to accept his answer, I'm sorry. :( But your answer was very useful, I voted it up! Thanks again!