# Views "Content: Title" as a select list exposed filter?

Tags: entities, views

Now I know [how to display the "***Content: Title***" exposed filter field as an autocomplete widget](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/44856/views-content-title-as-an-autocomplete-exposed-filter), but can I output this field as a **select list** too?
Are there any modules to do that?

(I know this can be too resource consuming, when having *lots* of nodes in a given content type, but currently I only have some of them, so now I'd like to display it as a select list.)

[This topic](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/20641/views-exposed-filters-dropdown-select-list) has been closed, linking to [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/6611/how-do-i-add-dropdowns-in-filter-criteria-in-views-module) one, but maybe there's already a module to do that since.